# Localized dropdown with all month names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I am trying to make in Rails 4 a dropdown with all the months. I do it like this:

```
<select >
    <% (1..12).each do |month| %>
        <option value="<%= month %>"><%= Date::MONTHNAMES[month] %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

The problem now is that I would like to localize it, but I can't apply the `locate` method on simple Strings with the names of the months.

How could I solve this?

**Update**

I know I can translate them myself, but I was hoping, since Rails is so kind to give me the names in English, if there was any way that Rails could give it to me in other languages as well.

Answer (score 3):

`I18n.t("date.month_names")` gives an array just like `Date::MONTHNAMES` with nil as the first element, but localized.

For the options we want an array of pairs:

```
I18n.t("date.month_names").drop(1).zip(1..12)
=> [["January", 1], ["February", 2], ["March", 3], ["April", 4], ["May", 5], ["June", 6], ["July", 7], ["August", 8], ["September", 9], ["October", 10], ["November", 11], ["December", 12]]
```

You can pass this to `options_for_select` or `select`.

```
select(:thing, :month, I18n.t("date.month_names").drop(1).zip(1..12))
```

Comment: Late answer but I hade the same problem and the existing answers seemed hacky and convoluted.

Comment: This can be combined with the `rails-i18n` gem which contains localizations for tons of languages.

Comment: Just wondering - why is the first one nil?

Comment: @GregBlass Array access is normally 0 based, so if the nil element would not be there then plugging in month `1` would give Februrary. By adding a nil element first, month `1` (second element) is actually January, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First, install the [rails-i18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n). This gem contains localization data for a lot of locales. Take a great care which version of the gem you install based on the Rails version (as documented in the README).

Next, define the locales (as again described in the README) that you need to support in your `application.rb` config:

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:cs, :en, :es, :de]
```

Then, you can simply use **`I18n.l`** (i.e. the `localize` method of I18n) anywhere and make it print only the month name in the given locale (see some more info on `localize` [in the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) and [`strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for the formatting options).

You need to generate a sequence of dates (e.g. the 1st days of all months) in a year for this first.

```
# generate dates for each month in the year
dates = (1..12).map{|d| Date.parse("#{'%02d' % d}/01") }
# => [Fri, 01 Jan 2016, Mon, 01 Feb 2016, Tue, 01 Mar 2016, Fri, ..., 01 Nov 2016, Thu, 01 Dec 2016]

# use these dates to get month names in the given locale     
dates.map{ |d| I18n.l(d, format: "%B", locale: :en) }
# => ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", ..., "November", "December"]

dates.map{ |d| I18n.l(d, format: "%B", locale: :de) }
# => ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", ..., "November", "Dezember"]

dates.map{ |d| I18n.l(d, format: "%B", locale: :cs) }
# => ["leden", "únor", "březen", "duben", "květen", ..., "listopad", "prosinec"]
```

Comment: `(1..12).map{ |d| Date.parse("#{'%02d' % d}/01").strftime('%B') }`

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with.  This generates the select list options, with the month number as the value, and generates the properly translated month name using the built in Rails translations via `I18n` as the text....all in one line!

`(1..12).map {|m| I18n.l(DateTime.parse(Date::MONTHNAMES[m]), format: "%B")}`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

But you still can call the translation explicitly:

```
<option value="<%= month %>"><%= t(Date::MONTHNAMES[month]) %></option>
```

where `month` is a number of month, `Date::MONTHNAMES` is an array of dotted and downcased months, like `['.january',...]`, and you have a translation files:

**config/locales/en.yml**:

```
en:
   :controller:
      :action:
         january: January
```

whene `:controller` is a controller name, and `:view` is an action names responded to view (exactly view name).

Comment: Yes, but then I have to do manually the translation. I was hoping if there is anyway that Rails handle the translation for me, since it already could give me the names in English...

Comment: Well, the names are provided in English automatically, so I was wondering if I could get them also in another languages automatically.

Comment: @Dbugger they provided along with such yaml records for eny language you created it.

Comment: @Dbugger I have meant that translations to other languages than english is supported only when translation files for those languages are available, and those files should be usually manyally created.